# Printing from Win RT Application (Windows 8.1 App)

Tags: printing, winrt-xaml, windows, epson

I am developing a POS application in windows 8.1 (Universal App).
Order receipt will be printed from the application and even I am able to do so.

**Printer** - EPSON TM-U220D

**Input** - A grid is being created pragmatically with dynamic content within the ViewModel. So this grid is the input for printer

**Output** - In the print preview (Attahced pic 1) all looks good but when the receipt is actually printed then content is cut off from the end   (Attahced pic 2)

PIC 1
[image]

PIC 2
[image]

**Observations** -

1. If I print a normal text file manually using print command (Right click file and then print), then all content is printed perfectly.
2. If I print that SAME content, from the application, by creating Dynamic grid, then with Small font size print is good but with bit bigger font size content again cuts off.

**Tried** -

1. Optimized the code for Creating Gird, by specifying height

**Questions**-

1. If preview is all good then why not output
2. Did anyone tried using ePOS-Print_SDK_141020E for Windows Store app?

**Generate Dynamic Grid Code**

```
 private void AddRows(Grid grid, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            row.Height = GridLength.Auto;
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
        }
    }

    private void AddColumns(Grid grid, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        }
    }

    private TextBlock CreateTextBlock(string text, Color color, FontWeight fw, double fs = 10, int thick = 5)
    {
        if (color == null) color = Colors.Black;
        TextBlock txtBlock1 = new TextBlock();
        txtBlock1.Text = text;
        txtBlock1.FontSize = fs;
        txtBlock1.FontWeight = fw;
        txtBlock1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
        txtBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        txtBlock1.Margin = new Thickness(thick);
        return txtBlock1;
    }


    private async Task<Grid> CreateDynamicWPFGrid()
    {
        Grid ParentGrid = new Grid();
        AddRows(ParentGrid, 8);
        /* Start First Grid*/
        Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
        DynamicGrid.Width = 230;
        DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        DynamicGrid.Margin = new Thickness(24, 0, 0, 0);

        AddColumns(DynamicGrid, 2);
        AddRows(DynamicGrid, 3);

        TextBlock txtBlock1 = CreateTextBlock(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yy"), Colors.Black, FontWeights.Normal);
        Grid.SetRow(txtBlock1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(txtBlock1, 1);
        .
        .
        .
        .
        Return ParentGrid;
    }
```

**Printer Events Code**

```
       //Register Print Contract
    async Task RegisterPrintContract()
    {
        PrintManager manager = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        manager.PrintTaskRequested += OnPrintTaskRequested;
        await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }
    //Unregister Print Contract
    void UnregisterPrintContract()
    {
        PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= OnPrintTaskRequested;
    }
    void OnPrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        // If I need to be asynchronous, I can get a deferral. I don't *need*  
        // to do this here, I'm just faking it.  
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        PrintTask printTask = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("My Print Job", OnPrintTaskSourceRequestedHandler);

        printTask.Completed += OnPrintTaskCompleted;

        deferral.Complete();
    }
    void OnPrintTaskCompleted(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Tidy up.  
        this._document = null;
        this._pages = null;
    }
    async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequestedHandler(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.GetDeferral();

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
          () =>
          {
              this._document = new PrintDocument();
              this._document.Paginate += OnPaginate;
              this._document.GetPreviewPage += OnGetPreviewPage;
              this._document.AddPages += OnAddPages;

              // Tell the caller about it.  
              args.SetSource(this._document.DocumentSource);
          });
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    void OnAddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop over all of the preview pages and add each one to  add each page to be printied
        // We should have all pages ready at this point...
        foreach (var page in this._pages)
        {
            //this._pages[page.Key]
            this._document.AddPage(this._pages[page.Key]);
        }

        PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;
        // Indicate that all of the print pages have been provided
        printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
    }

    async void OnGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid x = await CreateDynamicWPFGrid();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
          () =>
          {
              // NB: assuming it's ok to keep all these pages in  
              // memory. might not be the right thing to do  
              // of course.  
              if (this._pages == null)
              {
                  this._pages = new Dictionary<int, UIElement>();
              }
              if (!this._pages.ContainsKey(e.PageNumber))
              {

                  this._pages[e.PageNumber] = x;
              }
              if (this._document == null)
                  this._document = new PrintDocument();
              this._document.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, this._pages[e.PageNumber]);
          }
        );
    }
    async void OnPaginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
          () =>
          {
              // I have one page and that's *FINAL* !  
              this._document.SetPreviewPageCount(e.CurrentPreviewPageNumber, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
          });
    }
```

Comment: When you say you are creating a 'dynamic grid', do you mean a xaml grid rendered to an image, or just printing text in a grid format? What is your actual printing code? It *sounds* like you're printing an image rather than text, and either the image is being cut off because the printer/driver thinks it has reached the end of the page, or there is a limit on the size of an image that can be printed. Just guessing though. Posting your actual code may help. Also, if you can update to Win10 the UWP framework has POS printer API's.

Comment: Hi Yort. I have posted the code now. Please check and let me know if you understand the problem. 
And I can't update to windows 10

Comment: Hmm, not sure. It is odd the preview works and the print doesn't. OnPaginate and and OnGetPreviewPage both seem to be async without a deferral? I wonder if that's got something to do with it. In theory the event handle should be finishing before your dispatched code executes, so could be race conditions?

Comment: There is just no point in pursuing this, you cannot print fast enough to have an acceptable POS solution.  Using the Windows.Devices.PointOfService.PosPrinter class is essential.

Comment: Hans, does It mean that windows 8.1 is not so capable of printing with EPSON printers?